# why I am getting bad request (code: 400 error) with s3 bucket and angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to my s3 bucket using linode storage and I am getting the code 400 bad request error.

here is the code I am running:

```
export class UploadComponent {

  fileSelected: any = null;
  config = {
    bucketName: 'cfe2',
    dirName: 'test',
    region: 'ap-south-1',
    accessKeyId: "",
    secretAccessKey: "",
    s3Url: 'https://cfe2.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com'
  }
  S3CustomClient: AWSS3UploadAshClient = new AWSS3UploadAshClient(this.config);

constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChangeFile(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0])
    this.fileSelected = event.target.files[0]
  }

  async handleSendFile() {
    console.log("handleSendFile")
    await this.S3CustomClient
      .uploadFile(this.fileSelected, this.fileSelected.type, undefined, 
        this.fileSelected.name, "public")
      .then((data: UploadResponse) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err: any) => console.error(err))
  }
  
}
```